# how to print the value of a function-pointer from a structure

Tags: c

The value contained in the function-pointer   " *fun "  from the structure below is wrong printed and i can not find the way to print it right. What's the right code for it? The code:

```
struct t {                      //structure definition
    int a;
    int (*fun) (int  a);};


int get_a (int  a) {            //function definition
    a = a*2;
    return a;}

int main () {
    t test;                     //variable creation
    get_a(5);                   //function activating
    test.fun = &get_a;          //assignation to the pointer function
    printf ("%d\n",*(test.fun));    //THE NUMBER 4199360 IS WRITTEN INSTEAD OF '10'.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, `printf ("%d\n",*(test.fun));` is **undefined behaviour**. Second, why do you expect a function pointer to have any particular value such as 10?

Comment: There is no standard compliant way to `printf` a function pointer.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to print the return value of the function pointer when passed an argument of `5`.

Comment: "test.fun" gets the value from the function "get_a". The value is get_a(5) = 10. So 10 is the number I expect to be printed.

Comment: @SofleshhitutHaHaredim test.fun is pointer not an integer to hold integer value

Comment: If you want the return value of `test.fun` to be printed, you need to do `printf ("%d\n",test.fun(5));`.

Comment: Your title asks about printing a function pointer, but the comment in your code implies that you want to print the value returned by the function. Please update your question to indicate what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function with argument value as 5
Also to print the return value, don't use * since it is just an int

```
printf("%d\n", test.fun(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your title, you ask about printing the value of a function pointer. There is no portable way to do that. The `printf` format `%p` is used for a pointer value of type `void*`, but you can't portably convert a function pointer to `void*`. (On some systems such a conversion does yield a meaningful result, and you can print a function pointer using

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)test.fun);
```

but that's not strictly portable.)

However, your comment indicates that you what the value printed to be `10`, which implies that you're trying to print, not the value of the function pointer, but the value returned by a call to the function. To do that, *you have to call the function*:

```
printf("%d\n", test.fun(5));
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly dereference the function pointer. A function call actually requires a function pointer value as its prefix. Most commonly it's a function name which is implicitly converted to a pointer. In this case the prefix is an actual function pointer, and no implicit conversion is needed.

Comment: Keith Thompson: I get:  error: too few arguments to function
     printf ("%d\n",test.fun());

Comment: @SofleshhitutHaHaredim: Right, you need to pass any required arguments. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct t 
{                      
    int a;
    int *fun;
}test;


int get_a (int  a) 
{           
    a = a*2;
    return a;
}

int main () {
    int c;
    c=get_a(5);                   
    test.fun = &c;         
    printf ("%d\n",*(test.fun));
    return 0;
}
```

This is the best way to get the output, the changes i have made is simple ,just run the program you will get output 10

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you ought to correct the compiler errors and warnings you should have gotten.

```
t test;
```

should really be

```
struct t test;
```

You are also missing an include of `stdio.h`.  The real problem though is your belief that the function pointer somehow has knowledge of the `a` field of the struct that contains it.  The point t.fun is simply a memory address.  The declaration tells the compiler to expect it to be the address of a function taking and int and returning an int.  Any time you expect the underlying function to be called, you need to pass it the expected argument.  As it is, you are printing the value of whatever got compiled at the start of the function, clearly not what you want.  Most likely you want you main function to look like this

```
int main () {
 struct t test;
 test.a = 5
 test.fun = &get_a;   
 printf ("%d\n",test.fun(test.a));

 return 0;
}
```

The orignal line calling get_a(5) does nothing with the return value.